# Are B&W images of digits linear seperable

Tags: linear, bayesian-network, perceptron

Given an image, expressed in the vector $\vec{v} = (v_1, \dots, v_n)\in \{0,1\}^n$

The vector $\vec{v}$ can represent images of the numbers 0 to 9. How do I know if this is linear seperable? Given the high dimension when we get big pictures, it becomes hard to reason about this, altough I think the answer is pretty straightforward.

What is a correct and (preferably) mathematical way of reasoning about this? I believe they are not linearly seperable, but I wouldn't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

First the question is not very clear to me. We we say "linear separable", we usually mean binary classification. Because when you draw a line or hyperplane, the data points will be divided into two parts. But in your question, it seems you want to do multi-class classification. then "linear separable" is not well defined.

I will focus on binary classification case. We can use [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to do it.

Details can be found in [Testing for Linear Separability with Linear Programming in R](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/testing-linear-separability-linear-programming-r-glpk/).

Note, GLPK is just one solver, and R is the interface to build the problem. If you know other solvers, you can directly write other code (say python) to build MPS file or LP file to solve.

Comment: Well, we could start looking at just one class and its complement right? If we can show those are not linear seperable we're done. 
I was mostly wondering if there's a quick and elegant way to show something is not linear seperable